# How do you use a Powerup in Manual Mode In Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I am trying to use a mushroom powerup in manual mode which is the B button, but instead when i press B I drift instead.

Comment: Perhaps you or someone else customized the controls and forgot about it.

Answer (score 5):

According to the instruction manual

[scan of instruction manual http://www.wiichat.com/forum/attachments/nintendo-wii-hardware/4200d1237934432-mario-kart-controller-mkwcontrolleroptions.jpg](http://www.wiichat.com/forum/attachments/nintendo-wii-hardware/4200d1237934432-mario-kart-controller-mkwcontrolleroptions.jpg)

Depending on which control scheme you're using, "Use Items" is mapped to either <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, or the D-pad.

#### Wiimote (horizontal)

D-Pad up (launches item forward if possible) or down (launches item behind if possible).

#### Wiimote & Nunchuk

<kbd>Z</kbd>

#### Classic Controller or NGC controller

<kbd>L</kbd>